# Load jquery tab content elsewhere

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

So there's this app for which the content is dynamically generated when certain tab is selected. What I'd like to do is to somehow load the content from only one tab into a page. Any ideas where to start? Missing details? Please ask. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Please elaborate on "load the content from only one tab into a page".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up including the html file which describes the content containers and calling the javascript function which would be called when the tab is selected.